# How to use a personal smartcard (x509 Certificate) in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, x509, x509certificate2

Since smartcard's private key cannot exportable, I need to use **StoreLocation.My** instead of **StoreLocation.LocalMachine** on a web site.

```
  string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

  int count = 0;
  X509Store store = null;
  X509Certificate2Collection col = null;
  X509Certificate2 cert = null;

  store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser); // Certificate store locaiton is Personal
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  col = store.Certificates;
  count = col.Count;
```

In development environment (Visual Studio) the code works as expected. When it will run on IIS I cannot find any personal certificate installed. I've tried to create an application pool which runs as my Windows account identity instead of Network Service or other application identity, and it didn't help.

How can I use personal certificate under IIS environment?

Comment: Import certificate (with private key) to LocalMachine\My (Personal) store using `certlm.msc` and assign rights on private key to account that IIS pool runs under (i.e. by default `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`).

Comment: @pepo you cannot assign permissions to certificate stored on a smart card. It would be better to know why you want to open certificate from smart card on IIS server.

Comment: Why do you need to load such a certificate in your web app? Client certificates should be loaded by the web browser, and then pass to your web app on IIS.

Comment: I sign PDF files automatically. Currently I use Windows Form app to sign on user's desktop session. It monitors a folder and when a pdf created it signs and saves signed copy of pdf. Web site creates the PDF then check for existance of signed copy for a while.

Comment: You need to write the code that would pass PIN to CSP provider in order to use the certificate stored on a smart card.

Comment: How do you solve this problem? I have this error.

Comment: @VOLVO I have used real machine instead of virtual machine. It is Windows 7 instead of a server. I log in automatically. I run an application and sign pdf files. And then IIS/website/C# code checks for signed file. The trick is working on my personal profile with my own credentials.